# Are these similarities coincidental?

Tags: english, etymology, swedish

The word "betray" sounds similar to the Swedish word "bedra". The Swedish word means betray or commit a fraud.

The word "fraud" sounds similar to the Swedish word "förrådd" which means betrayed.

Is that a coincident or did the words have common etymology?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is purely coincidental.

**Betray** comes from French *trahir* (prefixed with *be-*), ultimately from Latin *trado,-ere* (to give something over), itself being a derivation of *trans-* (over) & *do,dare* (give).

**Bedra** comes from Germanic *dreugan* (prefixed also with *be-*), etymologised as PIE *dhrewgh-* (mislead) which is also coincidentally the most probable stem, from which Latin **fraus, fraudis** comes from!

**Förrådda**, on the other hand, comes from Germanic *rédan* (to advise; compare the prefixation with Czech *pro-radný*).

Comment: Very interesting that the question could be answered this way. It looks as if you know many languages and their origins.

Comment: @DacSaunders. There are such things as etymological dictionaries.